# Module 'video' is not available

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angular-fullstack

I am using Angular-fullstack as a generator. I have generated a route called video. But when I run grunt test:client I shows me this error -

```
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'video' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
  http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/$injector/nomod?p0=video
```

The test code is generated by angular-fullstack. Here is my test code -

```
'use strict';

describe('Component: VideoComponent', function () {

  beforeEach(module('video'));

  var VideoComponent, scope;

  beforeEach(inject(function ($componentController, $rootScope) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    VideoComponent = $componentController('VideoComponent', {
      $scope: scope
    });
  }));

  it('should ...', function () {
    expect(1).to.equal(1);
  });
});
```

And here is my controller code that I am testing for -

```
'use strict';
(function(){

class VideoComponent {
  constructor() {
    this.message = 'Hello';
  }
}

angular.module('video')
  .component('video', {
    templateUrl: 'app/video/video.html',
    controller: VideoComponent
  });
})();
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong here. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run into the same problem while working with the angular-fullstack for the first time. I think you have to change the component name to 'video' where you described your test cause you have video as the component name in your controller.

```
describe('Component: video', function () {

  beforeEach(module('video'));
  .......
  .......
```

Comment: will it work if I change both component name to `VideoComponent`?

Comment: changing both to `video` worked. Let me check the other one.